# My Tablet is freezing or waiting too long because of my application?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I write a project.It is include webservices,sqlite and background service.In my previous version it is ok.And then ı do some asycn task and thread.After then my customer say when i run your project it is almost freezing or waiting too long.And program asked it is nor respond waiting or force close.I have no idea why but can anybody give me some suggestion? I dont know where i must looking for?

Comment: You are probably running long-running tasks in the GUI thread.

Comment: If ı wrong tell me, asycn is closing auto..I must close smth in it?

Comment: use progress or process dialog for long running tasks.

Comment: Yes i done but anybody use their other appps.I think it is not related progress dialog.

Comment: post code. your question is too fuzzy.

Answer (score 1):

It can be - `SocketTimeOutException`, when u send requests and wait for response too much. 
Wrap yout request in `try{...}catch(...)`

After that put breakpoint, launch application, turn off your internet connection and turn on, then fast resume your application and do request.

Android OS switches between networks not quickly, it takes some time, in this time u can get freezes in your application, because you wait for response.